# How to match a row with Excel column and VLOOKUP the value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, vlookup

I have two sheets with two tables that look like this:

Table 1:

| Index | category |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | Cars |
| 5678 | Trains |
| 9101 | Motorcycles |
| 177 | Motorcycles |

Table 2

| Index | Cars | Trains | Motorcycles |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 100 | 150 | 15 |
| 5678 | - | 200 | 167 |
| 344 | 355 | 455 | 156 |

I want to match the category rows from table 1 with the assigned value that is available in table 2 by matching the name.

I have tried:

```
vlookup('Table1'!A2,"Table2"!A:D,Match(B2,'Table2'A1:D1))
```

but this doesn't work. So the table should look like this:

| Index | category | Values |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | Cars | 100 |
| 5678 | Trains | 200 |
| 9101 | Motorcycles | - |
| 177 | Motorcycles | - |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use Index and Match instead, Would continue to work even if you made changes to the tables,

> =IFERROR(INDEX(Table2,MATCH(A2,Table2[Index],0),MATCH(B2,Table2[#Headers],0)),"")

That would give you your result. A2 and B2 are the cells where your new table data starts, and you can change that to suit.